# Reading XML working in my computer but not in my Android phone

Tags: unity, c#, xml

Following code works perfect in my computer but when I try to run it in my Android Phone, it does not work.

```
string path = @"Assets\Layout\XML\file" + select.ToString() + @".xml";
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Name>));
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
List<Name> listnames = (List<Name>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
```

How can I make the code work in my Android Phone?

PS: It is C# , Unity.

Comment: Which language? Which framework? I'm guessing C# and .NET, but inquiring minds want to know!

Comment: Ow, I am sorry, I forgot to say it. It is C# @Almo

Comment: Unity? Looks like it might be Unity. If so, I might be able to help.

Comment: Yes, it is Unity. @Almo

Comment: May be you are hardcoding the path like "C:\" or "D:\", which prevents to find file on android.

Comment: @SamedTarıkÇETİN No, I wrote the path as @"Assets\Layout\XML\file" + select.ToString() + @".xml" . It is in the application folder. I think there is an another way to read the elements in Android phone.

Comment: Don't you have any logs, errors, logcat or something? -- Edit: Are you giving your application the required permissions to read data from storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost gave up but finally solved it. Unity converts everything to binary variable so that the first thing you need to do is to convert all xml files you have to txt and copy them to "Assets/Resources" folder.

Then, you can use following code:

```
    TextAsset asset = Resources.Load("file" + select.ToString()) as TextAsset;
    Stream s = new MemoryStream(asset.bytes);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(s);

    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Name>));
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
    List<Name> listnames = (List<Name>)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is "load an asset". Here's how:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetDatabase.html

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class ImportAsset
{
    [MenuItem ("AssetDatabase/LoadAssetExample")]
    static void ImportExample ()
    {
        Texture2D t = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets/Textures/texture.jpg", typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;
    }
}
```

`AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath` is the thing you need to use.

Comment: I have tried to write in many ways but I could not make it work. If you have a time, can you explain it with the same name I used in my first code? @Almo

Comment: How to get the textasset: `TextAsset asset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath("Assets\Layout\XML\file" + select.ToString() + ".xml");`

Comment: Don't use `\`, the only operating system that uses that is windows, neither ios nor android will support it. Use `/` which is universally supported in modern operating systems.

Comment: Right, I had just copied his code. My mistake.